# Accessing xml to edit ribbon elements

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I am using BCGPro for ribbon control in my VS15, MFC project. The ribbon syntax is saved in a form of xml. I want to create a tool that would load that ribbon.xml as a CBCGPRibbonBar element.

The problem is that it needs a resourceId, which is defined in rc2 of the respective project in which the ribbon is implemented, and i am trying to access that xml from another external project.

Project_1 -> ribbon implemented
Project_2 -> tool, that needs to load ribbon xml of Project_1.

P.S. please take care that it is not native MFC ribbon, but a BCG control.

Please suggest if anyone got any clue to perform this stunt. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All I need is to load the xml as ribbon successfully in the second project.

Comment: Also always explain the reason for doing -1 on the question.